# How do I customize Mailchimp email template?

Tags: email, templates, html-email, mailchimp

I customized a template for Mailchimp to use for the RSS compaigns and I noticed that the emails is sent plain without any customization and when you click view in browser the customization works just fine:

[image]

The template I'm using is a customized version of [Email Blueprints](https://github.com/mailchimp/email-blueprints/blob/master/templates/2col-1-2.html).

What am I doing wrong exactly?

Comment: My customization: https://jsfiddle.net/vqjrrj49/

Answer (score 0):

I just realized that my question is a duplicate of this one: [HTML email doesn't display correctly in Google Apps/Gmail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17038780/html-email-doesnt-display-correctly-in-google-apps-gmail)

And the answer to my problem was having inline CSS, I used this converter (as mentioned in the other question) and it worked: http://templates.mailchimp.com/resources/inline-css/